# Probability distributions associated with Markov chain

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let's say I have a Markov chain, with all the transition probabilities known, and there's a cost associated with each transition. The cost for transitioning from node $a$ to node $b$ is given by the pdf $f_{a \to b}(x)$. I know all of these probability density functions in advance.

I want to get from some starting node $A$ to an ending node $B$ following this Markov chain, and I want to calculate the total cost distribution associated with doing so. Knowing all of these pdfs $f_{a \to b}(x)$ and each transition probability $p_{a \to b}$, how can I calculate this 'total' cost pdf?

I want to apply this to a particular problem, but I don't have any formal training in probability or discrete math, so I may not be phrasing this question right.

Comment: It might help us answer if you added to your question the specifics of your particular problem: the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain, all the cost amounts and cost PDFs, and the start and end nodes/states.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a path integral.  What you would need to do is sum over all possible paths to go from a to b and weigh each path with its probability and its product of cost functions.  I.e., the total cost $K$ would be something like

$$ K(x) = \sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \mathbb{P}(p)\prod_{j \in p} f_{a_j \to b_j}(x),$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of all possible paths (it might be infinitely large) and the product over $j$ goes along the path.  E.g., if $p = \{a, s_1, s_2, ..., s_n, b\}$ then the product is

$$ f_{a \to s_1}(x) f_{s_1 \to s_2}(x) \cdots f_{s_n \to b}(x).$$

The difficult thing is certainly to find all possible paths here, but I guess we need a particular problem to tackle this.